# ReactJS: Reusing div element inside render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Updated My Question based on comments. Not able to make small snippets as its a legacy code with lot of interacting components and I am very new to React to understand all the components.

**I have the following GUI:**
[image]

If you see carefully I have multiple fields with corresponding dropdowns. This combination is represented within a Div in my code under a class within render() function.

> The problem is the Div code is repeatedly copy-paste to create a new
>   field and dropdowns. I don't want to repeat the whole div again and
>   again and want to replace it with some variable or function which
>   accepts Field name and DROP_DOWN_TYPE.
>
> I have tried many solutions but it resulted in various errors due to
>   onchange event.

**Repeated div is shown below:**

```
<div className="infoBlock">
    <div className="row align-items-center">
        <div className="col-6">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-4">
                    <label className="b_label">Category :</label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-8">
                    <Dropdown type="Categories" isMultiple={true} onchange={this.handleDDClick} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-6">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't show DropDown code because its a huge file. But its a normal drop down which makes a service call to populate its fields.

Comment: show Dropdown code and DropDownField usage

Comment: to which line the error points?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more clarity by making a demo kind of thing on codesandbox.io ?

What I feel is you are repeatedly calling the setState function according to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Either your state is being called repeatedly somewhere , or you need to bind that `this.handleDDClick` onto that `onchange` in `Dropdown` tag. Sometimes it gets triggered without actually any change happening in the dropdown.